# Laravel class Alias and facade not matching the actual file name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, facade

I'm trying to find path location of `Redirect` class. Its facade `return 'redirect'` in `getFacadeAccessor` method.

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

class Redirect extends Facade {

/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'redirect'; }

}
```

However I found that the real file responsible for this class definition is the '`Redirector.php`'. I can't find any where that alias '`Redirect`' to '`Redirector`' class so I am wondering how Laravel know about `Redirector` class is actually the `Redirect` component of container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look inside `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php`. It contains a class `RoutingServiceProvider` that has a method `registerRedirector()`.

That's where a new Redirector instance is injected into $app['redirect']. This can then be accessed via the Redirect facade you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Coul you tell me How you found that file has necessary method? Is it somewhere on the Laravel document that I'm missing?

Comment: I just had a look inside the files i thought might be relevant, and lo and behold, there it was. Redirect is a special case, it doesn't use its own service provider, so i just browsed the code and found it.

Comment: I'm glad you gave me such useful information. Thanks so much.